# Azure data factory data lake analytics linked service - failed because the connected party did not properly respond

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I have created a azure data factory to perform some USQL activities. while creating a New Linked Service (Azure Data Lake Analytics) getting following error.

while searching on this issue, found that developer facing different kind of issues with ADF.

Is anything am I missing?

Error: Failed to connect to ADLA account 'ad-cxp-analytics-c11' with error 'An error occurred while sending the request.'. An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to connect to the remote server A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 40.90.138.193:443 Activity ID: c218e103-f0a8-4b07-811d-014d39607dcc.

Comment: I would recommend to create a ticket to Microsoft because this kind of problems can be of their side.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you having looked into the [IR logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-integration-runtime).As its appears its seems the IR is having issues and you should have more info on the logs. Also capturing the performance metrics on the IR server will help.

Also as a short term solution ,you could try to enable the retry option on the activity.

[image]